# Match string case sensitive value with array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code!!!
I have one input field And
One of the array
I'm matching Input field entered value with arrray's list.
Prob : Unable to match capital value with array's list.
e.g if user enter one10 value so this one should be match or if user enter ONE10 in capital letter then this value should be match too.

```js
function myFunctiontwo(){
  var good = [
      "one10",
      "two10",
      "three10"
  ];
  var a = document.getElementById("code").value.split(' ');


  var foundPresent = a.some(elem => good.indexOf(elem) > -1);
  if(foundPresent === true){
    alert("correct");
      
  }else {
    alert("wrong");
      
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    

    <input name="code" id="code" placeholder="code" required>
    <button id="submit" id="sumbit" onclick="myFunctiontwo()">GO</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One simple method is to convert both to the same case then compare, try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Comment: @freedomn-m I have tried this but didn't worked for me.  var foundPresent = a.some(elem => good.indexOf(elem.toUpperCase()) > -1);

Comment: You also need to uppercase the `good` variable/content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the toLowerCase() method here. Assuming all your elements in *good* are lowercase you can just do *elem.toLowerCase()*

```
var foundPresent = a.some(elem => good.indexOf(elem.toLowerCase()) > -1);
```

When not you also should convert the array elements *toLowerCase()*

```
good = good.map(x => x.toLowerCase());
```

In the snippet below I added the element *"FOur20"* to the array.

As you can see *four20* will give you the message correct

```js
function myFunctiontwo(){
  var good = [
      "one10",
      "two10",
      "three10",
      "FOur20"
  ];

  good = good.map(x => x.toLowerCase());
  console.log(good);
  
  var a = document.getElementById("code").value.split(' ');


  var foundPresent = a.some(elem => good.indexOf(elem.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  if(foundPresent === true){
    alert("correct");
      
  }else {
    alert("wrong");
      
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    

    <input name="code" id="code" placeholder="code" required>
    <button id="submit" id="sumbit" onclick="myFunctiontwo()">GO</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, i was just busy by using this  var foundPresent = a.some(elem => good.indexOf(elem.toUpperCase()) > -1); never though toLowerCase() can be helpful. tnx it is working well enough now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first make sure the good array is all lowercase:

```
 good = good.map(word => word.toLowerCase());
```

Then, you can always convert to lowercase and check if it exists in the good array

```
  var foundPresent = a.some(elem => good.contains(elem.toLowerCase()));
  if(foundPresent === true) {
     alert("correct");    
  }
  else {
     alert("wrong");
  }
```

Comment: Yes... i was about toUpperCase() only and wasted my time by using this. never thought of lowercase. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @mdserver this assumes your array is *always* lowercase.  The key is to make them the *same* case - by applying toUpper/toLower on both sides.

Comment: i mentioned it earlier but i appreciate your comment and edited again to make it clearer (: